# Restructuring data depending on reoccuring values in R

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, data-structures

Right now, I try to restructure my data (it's about responsiveness of contacted people in a survey)  which has a structure like this:

```
df_test <- data.frame(
  Residence=c(rep("Berlin",10),rep("Frankfurt",10),rep("Munich",10)),
  Response=c(rep(TRUE,14),rep(FALSE,16)), 
  ID=c(rep(1:15,each=2)), 
  Contact = c(rep(c("Phone","Mail","In_Person","Phone","eMail","Phone"))),
  Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="day"), 30)
                                  )
df_test <- df_test[order(df_test$ID,df_test$Date),]
```

In the resulting dataframe, each line represents one contact event and, usually, all people (labelled by ID) have been contacted multiple times by different means:

```
#first 4 lines of dataframe:

    Residence   Response    ID  Contact     Date
2   Berlin      TRUE        1   Mail        2000-07-25
1   Berlin      TRUE        1   Phone       2000-09-25
3   Berlin      TRUE        2   In_Person   2000-02-06
4   Berlin      TRUE        2   Phone       2000-10-01
```

To get a nice overview with focus on the contacted people for e.g. plots, I want to create a new data frame in which every line represents one contacted person, with fixed values just appearing once (e.g. ID, Residence, Response) while contact-specific values (Contact, Date) are listed in each line like so:

```
#restructured lines in new dataframe from first 4 lines of original dataframe:

    Residence   Response    ID  Contact     Date        Contact.1       Date.1
1   Berlin      TRUE        1   Mail        2000-07-25  Phone           2000-09-25
2   Berlin      TRUE        2   In_Person   2000-02-06  Phone           2000-10-01
```

With the initial sorting by date i hope to also get the contact attempts in each line in chronological order.

While i don't have any code which is close to running, i tried to at least get a dataframe with an empty column and fill it with with the extracted IDs, without duplicates:

```
for (i in df_test[,"ID"]){
    
    if (df_test[i,"ID"] != df_test [i-1,"ID"]){
      df_test_restructured<-append(df_test_restructured,df_test[i,"ID"])
    
    }
    
    
  }
```

After many unfruitful attmempts, I figured there should be some existing and more efficient strategies or functions unknown to me. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance <3

EDIT: Ideally, each row would have the contact attempt listed in order, since people also have been contacted multiple times with the same medium. I want to extract info like e.g. people have mostly responded after the first reminder email after already having been sent an initial email

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want per person (ID) one row to show at what date with what (phone, email,..) there was a contact you could do something like this with `tidyverse`.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df_test <- data.frame(
  Residence=c(rep("Berlin",10),rep("Frankfurt",10),rep("Munich",10)),
  Response=c(rep(TRUE,14),rep(FALSE,16)), 
  ID=c(rep(1:15,each=2)), 
  Contact = c(rep(c("Phone","Mail","In_Person","Phone","eMail","Phone"))),
  Date = sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2001/01/01'), by="day"), 30)
)


df_test %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = Contact, values_from = Date)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [15]
#>    Residence Response    ID Phone      Mail       In_Person  eMail     
#>    <chr>     <lgl>    <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
#>  1 Berlin    TRUE         1 2000-01-04 2000-09-06 NA         NA        
#>  2 Berlin    TRUE         2 2000-03-15 NA         2000-05-19 NA        
#>  3 Berlin    TRUE         3 2000-11-05 NA         NA         2000-05-06
#>  4 Berlin    TRUE         4 2000-11-02 2000-03-29 NA         NA        
#>  5 Berlin    TRUE         5 2000-12-20 NA         2000-04-30 NA        
#>  6 Frankfurt TRUE         6 2000-02-23 NA         NA         2000-02-05
#>  7 Frankfurt TRUE         7 2000-08-30 2000-11-29 NA         NA        
#>  8 Frankfurt FALSE        8 2000-02-20 NA         2000-08-08 NA        
#>  9 Frankfurt FALSE        9 2000-12-11 NA         NA         2000-05-25
#> 10 Frankfurt FALSE       10 2000-12-21 2000-01-15 NA         NA        
#> 11 Munich    FALSE       11 2000-07-07 NA         2000-12-16 NA        
#> 12 Munich    FALSE       12 2000-08-26 NA         NA         2000-09-03
#> 13 Munich    FALSE       13 2000-05-02 2000-11-20 NA         NA        
#> 14 Munich    FALSE       14 2000-04-05 NA         2000-09-30 NA        
#> 15 Munich    FALSE       15 2000-09-26 NA         NA         2000-05-22
```

---

**New Addition based on your new target**

I am not sure if this is the tidiest way, but I guess it is what you are looking for.

```r
df_test %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  arrange(Date) %>% 
  mutate(no = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(no), values_from = c(Contact,Date)) %>% 
  select(c(Residence:Contact_1, Date_1, Contact_2, Date_2)) %>% 
  arrange(ID)
#> # A tibble: 15 x 7
#> # Groups:   ID [15]
#>    Residence Response    ID Contact_1 Date_1     Contact_2 Date_2    
#>    <chr>     <lgl>    <int> <chr>     <date>     <chr>     <date>    
#>  1 Berlin    TRUE         1 Mail      2000-01-09 Phone     2000-04-26
#>  2 Berlin    TRUE         2 Phone     2000-01-27 In_Person 2000-10-14
#>  3 Berlin    TRUE         3 eMail     2000-03-01 Phone     2000-07-14
#>  4 Berlin    TRUE         4 Phone     2000-05-19 Mail      2000-09-22
#>  5 Berlin    TRUE         5 Phone     2000-07-06 In_Person 2000-12-03
#>  6 Frankfurt TRUE         6 eMail     2000-07-05 Phone     2000-11-20
#>  7 Frankfurt TRUE         7 Phone     2000-02-06 Mail      2000-12-28
#>  8 Frankfurt FALSE        8 Phone     2000-04-03 In_Person 2000-09-06
#>  9 Frankfurt FALSE        9 eMail     2000-06-16 Phone     2000-06-24
#> 10 Frankfurt FALSE       10 Phone     2000-01-26 Mail      2000-05-02
#> 11 Munich    FALSE       11 In_Person 2000-02-15 Phone     2000-06-28
#> 12 Munich    FALSE       12 eMail     2000-03-22 Phone     2000-04-24
#> 13 Munich    FALSE       13 Phone     2000-03-21 Mail      2000-08-02
#> 14 Munich    FALSE       14 In_Person 2000-09-01 Phone     2000-11-27
#> 15 Munich    FALSE       15 Phone     2000-05-27 eMail     2000-07-09
```

Comment: Thanks! The permanent data looks exactly like I tried to, but it would be nice for the "contact" and "date" info to be listed chronologically, so columns could be interpreted like (in this order): "first attempt method", "first attempt date", "second attempt method", "second attempt date".

Answer (score 1):

You can start by doing:

```
> df_test %>% 
+   pivot_wider(names_from = Contact,values_from=Date)

# A tibble: 15 x 7
   Residence Response    ID Phone      Mail       In_Person  eMail     
   <fct>     <lgl>    <int> <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 Berlin    TRUE         1 2000-01-20 2000-02-18 NA         NA        
 2 Berlin    TRUE         2 2000-07-24 NA         2000-03-19 NA
```

Actually, plotting with your original df is really doable.

Comment: Thanks! The permanent data looks exactly like I tried to, but it would be nice for the "contact" and "date" info to be listed chronologically, so columns could be interpreted like (in this order): "first attempt method", "first attempt date", "second attempt method", "second attempt date".